# How do you architect a flash sale site?

Tags: reactjs, websocket, apache-kafka

If a page has say 30,000 items in inventory and we show them all as a list, how do we architect data flow to these page as Push, that does not overwhelm the user with too many updates that make it impossible to buy anything, because stuff is disappearing from under your mouse, on the page, as they get bought.

Answer (score 1):

Do not render all items as soon as they come through the WebSocket. Instead, buffer them and update very N seconds.

As you didn't show any code I can't provide it either. But since you tagged your question with React, I assume you're sending the WS data back to the UI (either with `setState` if using pure React or with a `dispatch` if using Redux).

You should make your WebSocket message handler logic a bit smarter so it can accumulate incoming messages and then use `setInterval` to update every N seconds, whatever you/the product owner decides.